# How can I find the longitude and latitude of cities from my data frame to graph using clusplot?

Tags: r

I am trying to find the longitude and latitude of a list of cities from my data frame (named K.regions)
Ultimately I am trying to cluster them on a graph. I used clusplot for the previous cluster plot and will need to eventually merge the information onto that graph.

For now though, I can't seem to get the longitude and latitude using ggmap and plotrix.
However, when running the code, I get an error message. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

````
 K.regions <- dplyr::select(K8, 13)
library("ggmap", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library")
library(plotrix)

 a1 <- as.character(K.regions)
 lonlat <- geocode(unique(a1)) 
 cities <- cbind(a1, lonlat)

```
````

When I run the code though, i get the following error message:

```
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=c(%22Dalian%22,%20%22Chongqing%22,%20%22Foshan%22,%20%22Beijing%22,%20%22Shanghai%22,%20%22Wuhan%22,%20%22Zhongshan%22,%20%22Yaogou%22,%20%22Ningbo%22,%20%22Sacramento%22,%20%22Orlando%22,%20%22Jackson%22,%20%22xiaogan%22,%20%22Ningbo%22,%20%22Dalian%22,%20%22Chicago%22,%20%22Tamarac%22,%20%22Jakarta%22,%20%22Lincolnton%22,%20%22Taichung%22,%20%22Hangzhou%22,%20%22Beijing%22,%20%22Beijing%22,%20%22Columbus%22,%20%22Suzhou%22)&sensor=false
geocode failed with status ZERO_RESULTS, location = "c("Dalian", "Chongqing", "Foshan", "Beijing", "Shanghai", "Wuhan", "Zhongshan", "Yaogou", "Ningbo", "Sacramento", "Orlando", "Jackson", "xiaogan", "Ningbo", "Dalian", "Chicago", "Tamarac", "Jakarta", "Lincolnton", "Taichung", "Hangzhou", "Beijing", "Beijing", "Columbus", "Suzhou")"
```

Any and all help is much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Would help to see some of either `a1` or `unique(a1)`. The URL string is incorrect, so something about how the character vector was passed to `geocode` is not right.

Comment: Can you copy the output of `dput( K.regions)` into the question please? I think that is the source of your problem as the whole list of cities is being fed into the geocode function.

Comment: I actually changed my data from cities to countries. There seemed to be some cities that didn't exist in geocode. Once I changed it to the countries, I was able to use geocode to find the latitude and longitude. Thanks for your help!!